# Dealing with mixed tuples - integers list

Tags: python-3.x, list, integer, tuples

Having the list say `[(4.23, 6.43), 1.23, 3.444, (1.342, 3.212)]`, my code should separate tuples and integers and then multiply numbers in tuples(to obtain a rectangle square), also get the circle square (`3,14 * radius ** 2` using integers in the list as radius, e.g. as I try to perform in my code. Then I need to compare all results and return a sorted list starting with the lowest value which was got as a result, but the list should have an appearance like the initial one, but sorted something like this:`[ ( 1.342, 3.212 ), 1.23, ( 4.23, 6.43 ), 3.444 ]`. I indexed all list items suggesting using indexes in any way to order the list and return the required sorted list.

```
def sort_by_area(seq):
    indexed_list = [item for item in enumerate(seq)]
    radius_list = []
    S_rectangle_list = []
    S_circle_list = [(3,14 * [item][0] **2) for item in radius_list] # getting circle square
    for id, i in enumerate(seq):
        if type(i) is tuple:
            for item in [i]:
                S_rectangle_list.append((id,(item[0] * item[1])))
        elif type(i) is float:
            for item in [i]:
                radius_list.append((id, item))
     print(S_circle_list)

sort_by_area([(4.23, 6.43), 1.23, 3.444, (1.342, 3.212)])
```

so, I have two questions:
1. How to get a circle square in my case because I obtain empty `S_circle_list = []`
2. could you suggest how to return the initial appearance to the ordered list like in the above sample?
I hope I was clear ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def sort_by_area(seq):
        area_list = []
        s_rectangle_list = []
        s_circle_list = []
        for id, i in enumerate(seq):
            if type(i) is tuple:
                for item in [i]:
                    s_rectangle_list.append((id, [(item[0], item[1]), (item[0] * item[1])]))
                    area_list.append((id, [(item[0], item[1]), (item[0] * item[1])]))
            elif type(i) is float:
                s_circle_list.append((id,[i,(3.14*(i**2))]))
                area_list.append((id,[i,(3.14*(i**2))]))
        area_list.sort(key=lambda y: y[1][1])
        result = map(lambda y: y[1][0], area_list)
        print(s_rectangle_list)  # [(0, [(4.23, 6.43), 27.198900000000002]), (3, [(1.342, 3.212), 4.310504000000001])]
        print(s_circle_list)   # [(1, [1.23, 4.750506]), (2, [3.444, 37.24396704])]
        return list(result)
    print(sort_by_area([(4.23, 6.43), 1.23, 3.444, (1.342, 3.212)]))  #  [(1.342, 3.212), 1.23, (4.23, 6.43), 3.444]
```

To answer your first question why s_circle_list is empty? Because you have run for loop for an empty array radius_list on line number 5 which you have added values later.  For the second question, hope the code helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works in general, but for it to pass all the tests, I had to add  `int` in  `elif type(i) is float or type(i) is int: `

Comment: also refactored the code throwing out some redundant strings